# The import org.apache.jena.query cannot be resolved

Tags: search, rdf, geospatial, jena

I want to calculate distance between sensors deployed in georaphical area using longitude and latitude in sparql query issued in apache jena 2.11.(Sensor description and observation are stored as RDF triple in sensor.n3, eclipse as IDE and Fedora 19, TDB as triple store)

I found that "**Spatial searches with SPARQL**" will help in this regard. But when I import package given at http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html `import org.apache.jena.query.spatial.EntityDefinition` in eclipse I get the error *The import org.apache.jena.query cannot be resolved*. When browsed the folder `../apache-jena-2.11.1/javadoc-arq/org/apache/jena directory it contains only 
(altas, common, web, riot)` there is no query folder which is the reason why import is highlighted in red.

I have one more doubt whether Apache Solr need to be installed ( I have downloaded solr 4.10.1) or just use build path to import external jar.

Comment: You need to separately download jena-spatial.  (Use maven to manage your dependencies.) You can use lucene instead of Solr.  Again, maven will load the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to separately download jena-spatial. (Use maven to manage your dependencies.) You can use lucene instead of Solr. Again, maven will load the dependencies. [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436781/the-import-org-apache-jena-query-cannot-be-resolved#comment41545072_26436781)